# Garbage collector destroys singleton objects when suspending the app

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, garbage-collection

I have an UWP app with two singleton classes, one is for sessioning containing user info and the other one contains a list. When a user minimizes the app, it gets suspended and the garbage collector destroys the session and permission class, so the user has no rights after maximizing the app.

I don't want to use the OnSuspending and OnResume events to save/serialize the classes because the session info is needed because of toast notifications.

Is there a way I can tell the garbage collector to leave them alone completely? 
I tried calling GC.Keepalive in the OnSuspending Event but that didn't help.

Edit: As requested, here is the code of my session singleton:

```
public class Session
{
    private Session()
    {

    }

    ~Session()
    {
        session = this;            
    }    

    private static Session session;

    public static Session Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (session == null)
                session = new Session();

            return session;
        }
    }

    public async Task<bool> LogIn(string username, string password)
    {
        ///
    }

    public void LogOut()
    {
       ///
    }


    public UserRights Permissions { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string Token { get; set; }
```

I tried to bypass it via the finalizer, but there is a small time between suspending and the garbage collection. In this time the problem still exists.
When I maximize the app after the garbage collection, then it works.

Comment: As far as I am aware Static objects (one common way to implement singleton pattern) do not get garbage collected under most circumstances. With that said an example of your code implementing the pattern and using the class that uses it would be helpful.

Comment: `GC.KeepAlive` is an *empty* method. It's only purpose is to make a variable appear to be required at least up until that method call appears in the code.

Comment: That's not a singleton. That's an almost-singleton. It's possible for two threads to race in `Current`s `get` and both observe `session` as `null`. If one thread then manages to create and return the `session` value before the other one overwrites it, you've got a problem.

Comment: From the GC perspective, with the code you've shown, there is no way that static Session field will be garbage collected when UWP app is minimized (I believe - suspended?). There must be another piece of the puzzle not shown here.

Comment: I wrote a "Debug.WriteLine("Session destroyed")" in the Finalizer of the Session class, and everytime the App is mimimized, the GarbageCollector collects a few seconds after and "Session destroyed" is written in the debug console. I don't execute something like GC.Collect() somewhere and IDisposable is not implemented too.

Comment: Then something must set to null your Session field. BTW, do you see single "Session destroyed" message?

Comment: I found the error. When you said something must set the session to null, there was just one possibility because only the LogOut method sets session to null. From outside it cannot be set to null, there is just get on session. It was my fault, i had another registration on the suspending event where the LogOut method is called. It was a  leftover before I implemented sessioning right. But you helped me, thank you very much! Piece of puzzle found ;)

Comment: Glad to hear that problem is solved!